# Dinamically changing some Queries Values inside an Href Attribute after clicking on specific elements. Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, get

I need to dynamically and simultaneously change more than one Query Value in a Href attribute (please see the `a` tag with `class="button"`).

When i click on specific elements (please see the `a` `class="tab-bagno"` and `class="tab-soggiorno"`) I want to retrieve their `data-name` and use that value inside the `a` tag with `class="button"`.

As you can see, the `a` tag with `class="button"` has two specific queries with non-assigned values (`&soggiorno=INSERT-SOGGIORNO` and `&bagno=INSERT-BAGNO`), my goal is to be able to put the `data-name` of the `a` tag with `class="button"` inside the two queries.

For now, I was able to correctly retrieve the `data-name` values, but i can't dynamically insert them inside the `href`.

here you can see my code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
        var nameSoggiorno1 = $('.tab-soggiorno').on('click',function(valueSoggiorno){
            //console.log(valueSoggiorno['currentTarget']);
            var nameSoggiorno = $(valueSoggiorno['currentTarget']).data('name') 
            console.log(nameSoggiorno);
        });


        var nameBagno1 = $('.tab-bagno').on('click',function(valueBagno){
            //console.log(valueBagno['currentTarget']);
            var nameBagno = $(valueBagno['currentTarget']).data('name'); 
            console.log(nameBagno);  
        });



        $('.button').each(function(){
                var currenthref = $(this).attr("href");
                if(currenthref.includes('&soggiorno=')){
                    var ti=currenthref.indexOf('&soggiorno=');
                    var ti2=currenthref.indexOf('&bagno=');
                    currenthref1 = currenthref.substring(0, ti);
                    currenthref2 = currenthref1.substring(ti, 100000);

                }
                 $(this).attr("href", currenthref1 + "&soggiorno=" + nameSoggiorno1 + "&bagno=" + nameBagno1);
                })
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a data-name="Ceramica Mirage - jewels, colore 16" class="tab-bagno">1</a>
  <a data-name="Ceramica Mirage - jewels, colore 14" class="tab-bagno">2</a>
  <a data-name="Ceramica Mirage - jewels, colore 6" class="tab-bagno">3</a>
</div>
                  
                  
<div>
  <a data-name="Parquet Castiglioni - Verniciato 05" class="tab-soggiorno">4</a>
  <a data-name="Parquet Castiglioni - Verniciato Naturale" class="tab-soggiorno">5</a>
  <a data-name="Parquet Castiglioni - Verniciato 09" class="tab-soggiorno">6</a>
</div>


<a class="button" href="checkout.php?&allestimento=Silver&soggiorno=INSERT-SOGGIORNO&bagno=INSERT-BAGNO" >select</a>
```

when I put this code online, the `href` return this: `checkout.php?tipo=43&stile=Elegance&allestimento=Gold&soggiorno=[object Object]&bagno=[object Object]"`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of faults in your code...

`nameSoggiorno1` and `nameBagno1` are the jQuery objects that are returned from the binding of the click events... that is why you're seeing the `[object object]` text being used.

I think you mean to use the `nameSoggiorno` and `nameBagno` variables... but you've put them as a `var` within the event handlers.

You are also setting the `href` attribute on the `.button` when the page loads, which means that the `nameSoggiorno` and `nameBagno` wouldn't have been ready anyway... so you need to set the `href` against the link when the selection is made.

And finally, you need to url-encode the query string data before appending it to the link.

Try the following, where I have moved the `var` outside of the event handlers, and changed the `href` attribute assignment accordingly.  I have also removed the `nameSoggiorno1` and `nameBagno1` assignments as they are pointless in this context.

```js
$(function(){
  var nameSoggiorno = encodeURIComponent($(".tab-soggiorno-default").data("name"));
  var nameBagno = encodeURIComponent($(".tab-bagno-default").data("name"));
  buildUrl();
        
  $('.tab-soggiorno').on('click',function(e){
    nameSoggiorno = $(this).data('name') 
    nameSoggiorno = encodeURIComponent(nameSoggiorno);
    console.log(nameSoggiorno);
    buildUrl();
  });

  $('.tab-bagno').on('click',function(e){
    nameBagno = $(this).data('name'); 
    nameBagno = encodeURIComponent(nameBagno);
    console.log(nameBagno);  
    buildUrl();
  });

  function buildUrl(){
    $(".button").each(function(){
      var currenthref = $(this).attr("href");
      if(currenthref.includes('&soggiorno=')){
        var ti = currenthref.indexOf('&soggiorno=');
        currenthref = currenthref.substring(0, ti);
      }
      $(this).attr("href", currenthref + "&soggiorno=" + nameSoggiorno + "&bagno=" + nameBagno);
      console.log($(this).attr("href"));
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a data-name="Ceramica Mirage - jewels, colore 16" class="tab-bagno tab-bagno-default">1</a>
  <a data-name="Ceramica Mirage - jewels, colore 14" class="tab-bagno">2</a>
  <a data-name="Ceramica Mirage - jewels, colore 6" class="tab-bagno">3</a>
</div>
                  
                  
<div>
  <a data-name="Parquet Castiglioni - Verniciato 05" class="tab-soggiorno tab-soggiorno-default">4</a>
  <a data-name="Parquet Castiglioni - Verniciato Naturale" class="tab-soggiorno">5</a>
  <a data-name="Parquet Castiglioni - Verniciato 09" class="tab-soggiorno">6</a>
</div>


<a class="button" href="checkout.php?&allestimento=Silver&soggiorno=INSERT-SOGGIORNO&bagno=INSERT-BAGNO" >select</a>
```

---

**Update**

In response to the OP's comment, you could default the initial values by adding a new class to the specific items, and using that to set the value.  Remembering to call the `buildUrl()` function afterwards.

I have updated the above code to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you! you are my savior! I was struggling so hard on this because I'm new to JS and it's difficult to me. I've this project to handle and it's beyond to my capabilities.
May I ask something more? If I need to not let the `var nameSoggiorno = ""` blank but dynamically have the number 4 Value if I'm not selecting anything? is this possible?

Comment: You're very welcome.  I don't get what you mean. Do you mean you want the `nameSoggiorno` to be pre-set to the encoded `Parquet Castiglioni - Verniciato 05` value?

Comment: If that is what you mean, I would add an extra class to the item such as `class="tab-soggiorno tab-soggiorno-default"` and the replace the initial `var` code with `var nameSoggiorno = encodeURIComponent($(".tab-soggiorno-default").data("name"));`.  You then need to add an extra call to `buildUrl();` after it as well

Comment: See updated code for changes.  If you need anything more, I would create a new question, otherwise this one will just keep exanding